# OpenGl lighting casting black shadow

Tags: opengl, java

I'm having issues with lighting that I can't figure out, namely solid black sections. Any ideas? [image]

Here's my fragment shader code:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;

out vec4 out_Colour;

uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
uniform vec3 lightColour;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;

void main(void) {
    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDot1,0.4);
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * lightColour;

    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection,unitNormal);

    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor,0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor,shineDamper);
    vec3 finalSpecular = dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour;

    vec4 textureColour = texture(modelTexture,pass_textureCoords);
    if(textureColour.a < 0.5) {
        discard;
    }

    out_Colour = vec4(diffuse,1.0) * textureColour + vec4(finalSpecular,1.0);
}
```

and vertex shader code:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;
out vec3 toCameraVector;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

uniform float useFakeLighting;

void main(void) {
    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    vec3 actualNormal = normal;
    if (useFakeLighting > 0.5) {
        actualNormal = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    }

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(actualNormal,0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
    toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
}
```

Comment: ThinMatrix anyone? ;)

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you remove specularity temporarily?

Comment: Nope, that's definitely the issue

Comment: Figured it out, I simply was using the wrong variable in my java code, loading the shine dampening twice instead of reflectivity. Oops!